# Alpine musl vs glibc - are they supposed to be compatible?

Tags: glibc, musl, alpine-linux

So I'm playing with Alpine Linux, which uses musl vs glibc.

I'm finding out that because of this choice I can't run Oracle Java, or static go binaries built under glibc.

Is musl supposed to be compatible with the more widely used glibc or are you required to recompile against it?  (I don't really expect big players like Oracle to do this!)

Comment: Here are some solutions for you. https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/11

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe either library aims to be ABI-compatible with the other.

Without ABI compatibility, yes: you will have to recompile and relink code against MUSL if you hope to run with MUSL.