# WSL2 distro shell can't launch a file copied from outside

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

## The situation in short

I can't launch an executable (binary or a script) in a WSL2 distro if it wasn't created inside this distro

I can launch scripts and binaries that were created inside the distro shell (not using /mnt/c or /mnt/d in any way)

But I can't launch anything that was created outside and copied inside from Windows (using /mnt/c or /mnt/d)

I can see the copied files in the file system, can "cat" them, can look them up with "which", but I cannot launch them by entering the path into the command line

The questions I have in regards to all this

- **How come that the shell can't see the files while utils you run from the shell can?**
- **How do I make the shell see files that were copied from outside?**
- **If I can't make the shell launch the files, then how do I launch them?**

## The Situation in detail

I have Windows 10 with WSL2 and two distros

- Ubuntu-20.04
- Alpine

In Ubuntu I have a "Hello, World!" project written in C

It compiles in Ubuntu and then and runs in Ubuntu just fine

But, when I copy it from Ubuntu to Windows

```
cp hello /mnt/d/
```

and then go to Alpine and copy it inside from Windows

```
cp /mnt/d/hello .
```

I then have trouble launching it inside Alpine

Here is the output of `file hello` command in Ubuntu with some extra formatting (just in case)

```
$ file hello
hello:
    ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, 
    x86-64, 
    version 1 (SYSV), 
    dynamically linked, 
    interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, 
    BuildID[sha1]=021352ab7bf244e340c3c42ce34225b74baa6618, 
    for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, 
    not stripped
```

### Here's what I have in Alpine

```
$ cp /mnt/d/hello .
```

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x    1 pavel    pavel        16760 Apr 19 19:07 hello
```

```
$ ./hello
-ash: ./hello: not found
```

Now same with a script copied from Windows

Copy the script inside Alpine from Windows

```
$ cp /mnt/d/hello.sh .
```

Checking the contents

```
$ cat hello.sh
#!/bin/ash
echo Hello!
```

Setting the execute permission just in case

```
$ chmod agu+x hello.sh
```

Trying to run it

```
$ ./hello.sh
-ash: ./hello.sh: not found
```

But, I can launch the hello.sh by explicitly calling the ash tool and passing the script path as the argument

```
$ ash ./hello.sh
Hello!
```

At the same time, a script created inside Alpine runs just by entering it's path to the command line

```
$ cat << EOF > hello-local.sh
> #!/bin/ash
> echo Local hello!
> EOF
```

```
$ chmod agu+x hello-local.sh
$ ./hello-local.sh
Local hello!
```

Also, I couldn't make a file that would run from one that wouldn't either by copying it with cp

```
cp hello.sh hello2.sh
```

or by copying it with cat

```
cat hello.sh > hello3.sh
cmod agu+x hello3.sh
```

## Why do I need to copy things from outside

It all started when I wanted to explore how Docker for Windows uses Linux namespaces to separate containers

The distro that Docker for Windows uses is called docker-desktop

The docker-desktop distro neither has utilities that I need for my experiments, nor a package manager to get those utilities

So I tried to copy them from outside

But now Docker for Windows studies is not the only concern

I want to understand this magic that is happening just as bad

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `file hello`  ? I suspect one of your systems is glibc based and the other is musl based.

Comment: Does `cat -vet hello.sh` show any `^M` characters?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, the issue with the hello.sh was ^M characters indeed. So now the problem is just with the binary

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, added the `file hello` output as you suggested

Comment: Does your Alpine system have the interpreter file `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` ? If not, try installing a [package that supplies it](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=ld-linux-x86-64*) such as libc6-compat.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, two shots out of two! Those were exactly why all this happened. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be fair, there really are three separate questions here, but not necessarily the questions you listed in your post:

##### Secondary question -- Why does your script that you copied to Alpine fail?

As @MarkPlotnick covered in the comments (and you confirmed), it was due to the script having DOS/Windows line endings (CRLF).  In general, try to avoid creating or editing Linux text files using Windows tools unless you are sure that they are using Linux line-endings.

###### Secondary question -- Why does your C program fail when you compile on Ubuntu and copy the binary to Alpine?

Also as @MarkPlotnick mentioned in the comments, this is because Ubuntu uses `glibc` as the standard library implementation by default, but Alpine uses `musl`.  See [a number of questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=glibc+musl) for more information.  The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33382707/11810933) in the list sorted by "relevance" is actually a pretty good one to start with.

###### Main question -- How to explore the `docker-desktop` distro

Really, your main goal seems to be how to gain access to certain tools inside the `docker-desktop` distro in order to learn more about it.

I was going to say, "don't" (with more explanation), but the reality is that I think it's a potentially good learning experience.  I've done it, to some degree, so who am I to say it's "too dangerous" or recommend against it? ;-)

I will give fair warning, though -- The docker-desktop distro isn't *intended* to be run by users.  Docker Desktop "injects" links and sockets into your other WSL2 distros (which you can enable/disable per-distro in Docker Desktop) so that its tools, processes, etc., are available to all your WSL2 (and PowerShell/CMD) instances.

I'd personally try to avoid making any *changes* to the `docker-desktop` distro itself.  They'll likely be overwritten anyway by Docker Desktop when it extracts a new rootfs.

However, we can still gain access to the tools we need by accessing them *from* another distribution, but without copying them *into* docker-desktop.

First, a note -- As I think you have probably already figured out,docker-desktop is also `musl`-basesd.  So you'll want to use tools from another `musl`-based distro like Alpine.

This can be easily accomplished by running the following line once in your Alpine instance (as root):

```
echo "/ /mnt/wsl/instances/Alpine none defaults,bind,X-mount.mkdir 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

That will add a mount to the Alpine instance into the tmpfs `/mnt/wsl` mount.   You can see [my Super User answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1659355/1210833) for more details on that.

Once you `wsl --terminate Alpine` and restart it, you'll have access to the Alpine files from any other WSL2 distribution.

As a useful (for your intent) example, install the `util-linux` package in Alpine to get access to the `lsns` command.

Then, in the docker-desktop distro (which I assume you already know to access with `wsl -u root -d docker-desktop`, but I'll include that command here for other future readers), to list the namespaces:

```
/mnt/host/wsl/instances/Alpine/usr/bin/lsns
```

The docker-desktop instance automounts at a slightly different directory than default (see `cat /etc/wsl.conf`), so you need to adjust the path to `/mnt/host/wsl` instead of `/mnt/wsl`.

But with that in place, you can run all (most?) of your Alpine binaries directly in docker-desktop without having to modify it directly.  If you have a script in your home directory that you want to run in docker-desktop, for instance:

```
/mnt/host/wsl/instances/Alpine/home/users/<yourusername>/hello.sh
```

Note that if you have a binary that requires a dynamically-linked library on Alpine, I'm assuming you'll need to adjust your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly, although I haven't tested.  For instance:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/host/wsl/instances/Alpine/usr/lib /mnt/host/wsl/intances/Alpine/usr/bin/<whatever>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to resolve all my issues with the info from @MarkPlotnick, but your answer gave me a lot of useful information as well

Comment: btw, I found out two things. 

First, it's not that dangerous to tinker with docker-desktop, since you can easily recreate it by deleting it and restarting Docker for Windows. All containers will be in place after that.


Second, docker-desktop has apk package manager that you can use to get utils from

Comment: @PavelTaruts Nice!  I didn't even check for `apk` since you mentioned needing to copy the files over, but that's good news.  And yes, while "not intended for user access", it should all be recoverable even if something does go wrong.  In general, WSL-type stuff is pretty resilient.